# Curve length on helicoid surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Find the length of curve given by:
$$v=\ln{(u+\sqrt{a^2+u^2})}$$
which is situated on the helicoid surface:
$$r(u,v)=[u\cos{v}, u\sin{v}, av]$$
and bounded by $v=0$ and $v=1$.

All I know is the formula for curve length:
$$L=\int_a^b{\left|\frac{d}{dt}r[u(t), v(t)]\right|}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

If we set $u=a \sinh(t)$, we have $v=\log(a)+t$ and the curve is given by
$$\gamma(t)=\left(a\sinh(t)\cos(t+\log a),a\sinh(t)\sin(t+\log a),a(t+\log a)\right)$$
and $t$ ranges from $-\log(a)$ to $1-\log(a)$. Its arclength is so given by

$$ \int_{-\log a}^{1-\log a}\sqrt{2a^2\cosh^2(t)}\,dt =\color{red}{\frac{e-1}{e\sqrt{2}}(a^2+e)}.$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you computed an expression under the integral $\sqrt{2a^2\cosh^2(t)}$?

Comment: @PawełOrliński: it is just $\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|$.